# Python False Concatenate Error?

Tags: concatenation

I can't seem to find my mistake.  I'm trying to write a simple program that encrypts messages using the caesar shift method.  However, I'm getting a funky error.  Program is as follows:

```
alphabet = {"a":0,"b":1,"c":2,"d":3,"e":4,"f":5,"g":6,"h":7,"i":8,"j":9,"k":10,"l":11,"m":12,"n":13,"o":14,"p":15,"q":16,"r":17,"s":18,"t":19,"u":20,"v":21,"w":22,"x":23,"y":24,"z":25}

alpha2 = dict (zip(alphabet.values(),alphabet.keys()))

def key(n):
    code = alphabet

    for i in code:
        code[i] = (code[i] + n) % 26

    for i in code:
        code[i] = alpha2[code[i]] 

    return code

def encode(x,n):

    my_key = key(n)
    message = []
    for i in x:
        message.append(my_key[i])

print key(13)
print encode("Message",13)
```

I find this absurd, because after running my `./caesars.py` the command line will return

```
{'a': 'n', 'c': 'p', 'b': 'o', 'e': 'r', 'd': 'q', 'g': 't', 'f': 's', 'i': 'v', 'h': 'u', 'k': 'x', 'j': 'w', 'm': 'z', 'l': 'y', 'o': 'b', 'n': 'a', 'q': 'd', 'p': 'c', 's': 'f', 'r': 'e', 'u': 'h', 't': 'g', 'w': 'j', 'v': 'i', 'y': 'l', 'x': 'k', 'z': 'm'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./caesars.py", line 56, in <module>
    print encode("Message",13)
  File "./caesars.py", line 27, in encode
    my_key = key(n)
  File "./caesars.py", line 15, in key
    code[i] = (code[i] + n) % 26
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Which clearly means that the first run through of the `key` function was successful, but when the `encode` functions tries to call the `key` function a second time it decides to have issues?  I have printed the types of n, and they come out as int.  I'm sure this is an oversight in my code, but for the life of me I can't find it.

Comment: `code = alphabet` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: You should use `code = alphabet.copy()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably expected

```
code = alphabet
```

to copy the `alphabet` dict into `code`. That's not what happens. This line evaluates the `alphabet` variable, producing a reference to a dict, and then makes `code` refer to that same dict. Setting items of `code` will also change `alphabet`, because both variables are names for the same dict. In particular, after

```
for i in code:
    code[i] = alpha2[code[i]]
```

all the values of `alphabet` are strings.

If you want a copy, you can make a copy:

```
code = alphabet.copy()
```

though a copy of `alphabet` might not be the cleanest starting point to construct `code`.